How to load a .sql file of sql statements to Snowflake
I have a .sql file which contains Snowflake sql statements.
Eg.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEES;
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (ID INTEGER, NAME STRING, AGE INTEGER, DEPARTMENT_ID INTEGER);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(ID,NAME,AGE,DEPARTMENT_ID) VALUES (1,'Steve',48,123),(2,'Mary',41,456);

The actual files I need to load can be over 20MB and include statements as above for multiple tables.
The INSERT statement values can exceed the max size of a varchar column in Snowflake.
Two additional caveats, 1) the files are in an AWS S3 bucket and 2) I need to process these using some kind of automation (not manual commandline Snowflake CLI).
Is there a quick and dirty way to load a .sql file of sql statements into Snowflake?
What I have tried so far:

Loading from EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FROM but the files exceed the max of 10MB for that statement.
Loading via python straight from S3 using Snowflake connector (execute_stream) (not successful so far my python is not great)
Loading into Snowflake table then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but discovered the INSERT values statement can exceed the varchar(max) <- I was wrong about this point, see answer below!

I have seen that the SnowflakeSQL or Snowflake CLI should be able to do this. Is there a way to automate those either via python or a Snowflake Notebook? I figured Snowflake would have a snazzy way to load large .sql files but I haven't been able to discover it yet.
Many thanks.

I'm asking because you mention automation and it feels like this is a process that will be repeatable. How are these files being produced and why are you shipping DDL statements AND Data via DML statements together? Can whatever that process is be replaced with separating the two and shipping your data in a more reasonable format like CSV, JSON, et al? This way you create objects with your DML using this existing process, and then load data through stage tables on your S3 data.

Taking the question at face value, snowsql may be the easiest route. You can check out the -f flag for running batch sql files like this here. Though it's a clumsy and slow way to migrate data. You'll also need to have the .sql file local in the system where you are running snowsql.

You REALLY want to avoid doing bulk insert's via the SQL parser. We did this back in 2016 as part of a lift and shift, using 10MB inserts, and the compile times of the INSERT could take 10 minutes to parse the SQL and 30 seconds to run the SQL. Back then compile was free, you will pay for this very bad style these days. If you are running from a Bucket, put your data in a CSV or JSONNL file, and use a COPY INTO command. To begin with we used a Node.JS app that ran on our servers, that looked like samhita's python.

Yes, I don't like the requirements either, it's from an external source so I don't really have control over how the data comes in unfortunately! :(

You could create a Python UDF(User Defined Function) in snowflake and invoke the UDF.

Logic to read the files in S3
 import snowflake.connector
 import pandas as pd

 def load_sql_file(file_path):
  ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
     user='your_snowflake_username',
     password='your_snowflake_password',
     account='your_snowflake_account'
 )
 cur = ctx.cursor()

 with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
     sql_statements = f.read().split(';')

 for statement in sql_statements:
     if statement.strip():
         cur.execute(statement)
 cur.close()




 """ In case file size is too large, 
 you could use chunks to load the data instead of loading at once like above"""                
 """with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
  sql_statements = []
     for line in f:
         sql_statements.append(line.strip())
         if len(sql_statements) >= chunk_size:
             cur.execute(';'.join(sql_statements))
             sql_statements = []

     if sql_statements:
         cur.execute(';'.join(sql_statements))

 cur.close()
 """


Create the UDF in Snowflake
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_sql_file(file_path STRING)
 RETURNS STRING
 LANGUAGE PYTHON
 RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
 HANDLER = 'load_sql_file'
 AS $$
 <Your Python code from above>
 $$;



3.Create an External Stage in snowflake to store the sql files in S3.
CREATE STAGE my_sql_stage
URL = 's3://your_s3_bucket/sql_files.sql/'
; 

4.CALL the UDF passing the sql file path
CALL load_sql_file('@my_sql_stage/sql_files.sql');


@samhita has a great answer that was also considered as a solution.
What I've done is basically the same just using SQL instead of python.
This was built inside our ETL tool so I could use local variables as you see below.
So the solution that I went with was as follows:

Load the .sql file into a Snowflake table directly from S3. I dumped it into a raw string table like so, create or replace TABLE RAW_SQL ( DATA VARCHAR(16777216) ); 
Next was to use SQL scripts to pull out each of the DROP / CREATE / INSERT statements and run them individually. I discovered that the INSERT values actually do fit in the varchar(max) ‍♂️, I was wrong about that.
Here is an example of the SQL to parse the INSERT INTO statement select replace(replace(concat(i,v),'`',''),$$'0000-00-00 00:00:00'$$ ,'null') as sql from (-- get insert and corresponding values clause (next row) select data as i,lead(data) over(order by row_id) as v from (-- get ordered list of stmts select data, row_number() over(order by 1) as row_id from raw_sql where data like any('INSERT INTO%','VALUES (%') ) ) where contains(i,'INSERT INTO')

You can see I had to do some cleanup of the incoming data (the replaces) but just put together the INSERT and VALUES clause and then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.
execute immediate $$${sql}$$

Where {sql} is a variable that holds the sql statement in a string.
Maybe it's not pretty but it works! :D
Thanks to everyone for your help and responses!
